# Chat apps reply in notification updating the user

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, whatsapp

How does the replies in notifications are updated with the servers? I know that whatsapp might be using a service to know about a new message and shows the notification. But when user reply in notification and click send, what exactly happens under the hood? I tried to log the network connection through charles but no http request was made through app for updating the chat. If it is using the existing xmpp connection then how is it updated without app coming in the background?

Can anyone suggest what happens here and how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

On Android 7+, a notification can contain a direct reply action. On the user inputs text and clicks reply, the data is sent back to the app.

[Reply Action](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#reply-action)